# How to refine WP-Query with further criteria

Tags: query-posts, wp-query

I have a WP-Query which I pass post IDs to via

```
'post__in' => explode(',', $my_ids)
```

I then want the ability to refine this list by a custom field value (if present).

I have tried including the custom field test in the args for WP-Query but I get my ID list **PLUS** the custom field post IDs (instead of my IDs filtered by the custom field value).

I also tried adding a query_post after the WP-Query as a filter but that didnt work at all.

How can I filter the query further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using **meta_query**? More details at http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query.

Comment: Thanks @Dee, I just found it!!!                                                         [http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-new-meta_query-with-custom-post-types]    this link was very useful too.

Comment: Great to know that!